# IE11 document.cookie not creating a cookie

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

I haven't been able to get a document.cookie to successfully create using IE11.

The following test code works in FF, Chrome and Safari. This is the only code that's in the test file:

```
function isCookie() {

    document.cookie = "testcookie";
    var cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1) ? true 
      : false;
    alert(cookieEnabled); //alert true
    alert(document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie"));  //alert 0
    alert(document.cookie); //alert testcookie
    return (cookieEnabled);
}
isCookie();
```

I have a Mac and used IE11 via VirtualBox to test as well as a separate Windows 7 laptop. In both cases, the alert messages above are 'false' and '-1' only in IE.

I checked the IE security settings and have Protected mode off and changed Security to accept cookies from all sites. Restarted IE after the changes, and still I can't get document cookie to write.

I'm looking in Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files. I see some cookies already in there from other sites, but not 'testcookie' from the test above.

Any ideas?

Comment: This one continues to stump. Any thoughts most welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this saves someone the time I spent on this problem.

The issue was that Microsoft does not allow cookies to be written when the URL has an underscore in it. Yep.

I confirmed this by changing our staging URL to use a '-' instead of '_' and cookies are now be written and read successfully in IE.

An article about this issue: https://ma.ttias.be/internet-explorer-wont-allow-cookies-subdomains-underscores/

Comment: It also checks the current url instead of the real location url so if you edit the url without redirecting, using `history.pushState` then the value of the `document.cookie` changes.